# Infinispan - set expiration for 4 hours

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, infinispan

I have this in my standalone.

```
<replicated-cache name="some-name" statistics-enabled="true">
<object-memory size="5000"/>
<expiration lifespan="3000" max-idle="3000"/>
<state-transfer chunk-size=="1000" timeout="6000"/>
</replicated-cache>
```

I want to set lifespan and max-idle for 4 hours but value are in milliseconds so is it OK to put 14400000?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just convert any duration you want to milliseconds and set it in the configuration.